# Add & remove form fields dynamically (Avoiding Duplicate field names)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that adds & remove form fields dynamically.

However, the issue comes when i delete an item and add a new row.
It ends up with a duplicate field name `item_3` for example, because `onDelete` will decrement variable `p`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var p = 1;
  
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (p < max_fields) {
            p++;
            var items = '<select class="form-control grey" name="form[item_' + p + ']">'
            
         });
    $(wrapper).append(items);
    
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.divItem').remove();
        p--;
    })
  
</script>
```

Comment: can you not just remove the p-- from your delete function?

Comment: Or not use any counter at all. Just remove the last matching element in the DOM.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery, yet it reads like you are adding `select` but removing `div`. Is that supposed to be like that? Also your brackets seem to be a messed up.